# SMIME not working anymore on iOS 11+

Tags: ios, smime

Since updating to iOS 11 and renewing my SMIME certificates they've stopped working for encryption.

Please see (Dutch) screenshots for the valid certificates and the grayed out options to choose "Encrypt" and "Sign".

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Profile and cert]

What options do I have, because the free Comodo service offers no solution.
You can get the certificates (in IE only) via https://secure.comodo.com/products/frontpage?area=SecureEmailCertificate

Extra steps: Download the root certificate, because if you don't the certificate will be red "Untrusted".

Comment: Just to mention that my Comodo certificates work fine for encryption on iOS 11.3.1.  I usually install them on my MacBook Pro first, then export them from the keychain there and mail them to myself.  Then install them on the iPhone.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but do the email addresses from profile and email account match? Do you have an older certificate on the phone for that email address?

Comment: @not2savvy yes to the first, no to the second.

Comment: @Redarm It shows me on my iPhone after exporting and e-mailing that the cert could not be verified.

Comment: On the last screenshot, what is displayed when you click on "More details"? And again, sorry for dumb idea, but have you made sure it was exported with its private key?

Comment: I just figured out that I could export it from Windows (PFX, with password) then import in Mac -> Then mail to myself in p12 format. It works for 1 address now.

Comment: @Rob "the cert could not be verified".  I see the same, but ignore it.  Encryption still works.